# Bones' axes rotate differently when moving along a curve

Tags: animation, rigging, bones, axis, curve-modifier

I made a project of a chain of bones moving along a curve. Everything seems correct except the axis of each bone rotates differently when the chain moves on a certain segment of the curve. How can I make all the bones' axes fixed in the desired direction as shown in image 2 wherever the chain moves on the curve?

This is the project, feel free to use it if you want.
[Project](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1dxALRe4IVzjV6B7j07J76MjrK1E34EM2/view?usp=sharing)

Thanks.

[image: Image 1.]
[image: Image 2.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Restating your problem: you've got a curve-deformed mesh object that is bone parented; you have a series of bones that copy location->copy rotation->stretch to vertex groups on that mesh.  Your bones' rest positions have their X axes pointing at the center of the curvature, but as you move the curve object (via its bone parent), some of the bones rotate through 180 degrees, which you don't want:

[image]

Copy location is fine.

There are a few problems here:

1. We're trying to copy rotation of vertex groups, and those vertex groups look like this:

[image]

2. We're doing a stretch-to after our rotation, which will change the copied rotation.

Vertex groups mark vertices, and vertices don't really have rotation.  Blender *tries* to do what it can to give you what you want despite the fact that this is inherently ambiguous.  But you can't even begin to define a rotation with only two vertices.  What is the world space rotation of that line?  What is its rotation when you rotate it in the axis of its own line, which doesn't change the position of the vertices at all?  A rotation needs to be defined by at least three vertices.

Just for kicks, let's see what Blender thinks the world space rotation of one of those lines is, by disabling the stretch to temporarily:

[image]

It thinks the rotation is exactly opposite the rest pose of your bone.  And then the stretch-to acts, swinging through 180 degrees through the shortest path it can to do so, which happens to be completely undefined at 180 degrees where all swings are the same length-- at the North Pole, where every direction points South.

Personally, I regularly discourage use of copy rotation (its behavior regularly violates intuition), and I especially discourage use with vertex groups, because even the concept of that doesn't make sense.

Instead, let's mark a vertex with another vertex group and then locked track that vertex, *after* we stretch-to:

[image]

I've marked just a single vertex on one side of Mth.012 with membership in VG "Group.032".  The bone copies location-- good.  It stretches to the average of location of Group.013, first rotating its Y axis to point at that location, then changing its scale.  And now, with the locked track constraint, set to lock Y and track -X (to match your desired picture), it rotates about its transformed Y axis to point its X axis directly away from the marked vertex.  Here's a pic of that marked vertex:

[image]

I've done this with one bone.  You'll have to do it with all of your bones.

Comment: Great, your way is very effective. I like your clear explanation and illustration.
Thank you much, Nathan.