# My cube with bones deforms a lot when I apply the curve modifier

Tags: modeling

I'm trying to make a conveyor belt like animation with a cube, but I need to export it to an engine that only works with bones.

I tried following this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iHbCHwPrm5w&t=81s

But when I finished and gave it a try, it looked like this.

[image]

Here are some screenshots of the modifiers I used:

[image]

[image]

The cube is supposed to resemble a conveyor belt, but it's all twisted, I don't know what caused this issue, my best guess is that some bones rotated when I added the curve modifier.

What did I do wrong here, and how do I fix this ?

[image]

Comment: Could you please add a screenshot of your modifiers? Its likely a conflict with the way you've set them up and I'd like some extra information about them.

Comment: Hello, thank you for helping me, I've added the screenshots to the post, if you need any additional information please ask.

Comment: consider uploading your file on https://blend-exchange.com/ so it's easier to help

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I uploaded it now.

Comment: Did you upload the right file?  There's no curve modifier on any mesh there, it's not all twisted up, and there are no constraints on the rig.  Might be good to add some more details in text to what you think you ought to be doing, and what leads to the twisted mesh we see in your pics?

Comment: Sorry, I accidentally uploaded the wrong file, it should be the right one now.

Comment: Looked at the new file.  I just answered this exact problem from someone else, lol: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/306809/bones-axes-rotate-differently-when-moving-along-a-curve/306829#306829 .  Hopefully that helps you?

Comment: It worked, thank you Nathan :)